# What are the implications of a company being "not in good standing?"

Tags: united-states, employment, corporate-law

I got a job offer from a company, and looked them up online at the registrar and their status is "not in good standing."  Should this be a factor in deciding whether to work for them?

Comment: How is this a question about the law?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, one of the reasons stated on the site was labor issues, so I was trying to find out if this would be enough of a warning for me not to accept the position; target audience being the employment attorneys.

Comment: The law does not answer the question of whether employers who don't pay taxes treat their employees well. What does your attorney advise?

Comment: When you say you looked them up online, what registrar are you referring to?

Comment: @user6726-I have no desire to argue; I just find it puzzling why you would advise me to discuss this with an attorney vs. here within the context of questioning if the content is the right topic for this group. Would not a conversation with an attorney potentially be appropriate topic here? Aside from the issue of lack of privacy. Again; I gave up defending some posts looong time ago.

Comment: @tubes - State Registrar.

Comment: You need to tag this "united states".  There is no registrar and no status of "in good standing" in England and Wales.  (There are related concepts of course, but there is no annual registration of companies - just annual filing of accounts.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about law.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has very little legal effect. It means that someone forgot to update their annual registration and pay the fee and could be resolved in half an hour with a small late fee payment. It is a sign of slight sloppiness, but is only sometimes evidence of something more serious.

For example, if a company moves to a new location without remembering to inform the Secretary of State, it might not get the annual report notice and thus fail to file. And, a company rarely has an occasion to double check that it is in good standing.

Usually, the only legal consequence is that the company can't commence a lawsuit without bringing itself into good standing and that another company can steal its business name (if it can do so without violating a common law trademark arising from use of the name). It does not significantly change the rights of parties dealing with the company in terms of property ownership, contract rights, etc.

This said, closer scrutiny than a company without that issue might be in order and the fact that you are checking at all means that there might have been other reasons apart from this fact to be concerned.

Comment: Thanks. I initially went to the site looking for the registered agent, but I only see a record for resident agent. Do you know if they are the same? I just want to ensure the contract I have with them is valid given that they modified a couple of items for me.

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Are there *other potential reasons* a company might not be in good standing, or could be unable to gain good standing, aside from just not paying the fee? For instance, could a company be not in good standing due to something more serious and/or nefarious? Or is it literally just a matter of being up-to-date on your paperwork and fees? I get that it’s *usually* just a logistical issue, but I wonder if there could be a possibility, however slim, of something more serious. Whether or not such a possibility exists would be a good addition to this answer.

Comment: @KRyan No. There are no other reasons that they would not be in good standing. The scenario you are worried about is one whether not just this, but all of its obligations are being disregarded (e.g. it also isn't paying its employees on time, isn't filing tax returns, isn't keeping accounting records, etc.) and this is just one issue among many, rather than the quite innocuous issue it would be standing alone. None of those other issues would deprive it of good standing, but companies that are in organizational disarray rarely remember to update their annual reports.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I think that could be a little more clear; maybe instead of “it *basically* means” say something like “it *only* means” in the beginning? The *basically* seems to imply that maybe there is a little more to it.

Comment: I know some accountants will handle some of the business paperwork and other small business services too (usually to compete with other accountants to get the account.) If you change accountants to save costs and one of those costs is they don't fill out all of these forms and updates and such, it's easy to not be fully aware of all the paperwork involved.

Comment: @KRyan It depends what organization they are "not in good standing" with - organizations can and do make their own definitions. For example a public company may be "not in good standing" with a stock exchange for failing to file timely or accurate accounts and reports of director's share dealings etc, or after being found to have broken accounting rules and conventions - which are much more serious issues than forgetting to tell some obscure organization that your company headquarters has changed its address. Even if they were genuine "mistakes" they can cost a lot of money to put right.

Comment: @alephzero "good standing" is a term of art in corporate law used almost entirely to refer to the status of a company with the Secretary of State or Division of Corporations or the equivalent. If you have a deficiency with a stock exchange or the IRS or something it isn't normally called "not in good standing."

Comment: Technically, a failure to be "in good standing" in the state of domicile could impact the ability of a foreign corporation to "do business" in another state.  One may also lose "good standing" by having a resident agent disqualified or a failure to pay franchise taxes.

Comment: @Upnorth Franchise taxes as trivially small except in Delaware and California and not all that huge even there. In twenty years I've never encountered a business prevented from "doing business" in any jurisdiction as a result of failure to be in good standing. It is always cheaper to resolve the problem than to having litigation that could in theory shut down a business and there are no good strategic reasons not to be in good standing.

Comment: @ohwilleke Yes, I was merely pointing out some of the additional ways that states may regulate "good standing", as a caveat to your comment that "There are no other reasons that they would not be in good standing." As you say, there is no GOOD reason not to stay in good standing.